# Get position center from UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need get the position of the origin center of a UIButton

for example

**this give the size of the UIButton**

```
  NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.origin.x);
  NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.origin.y);
```

How get the center of origin frame of the UIButton?? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 CGPoint centerPoint = [button center];
```

Comment: Adding to your NSLog comment, NSLog(@"%f,%f",centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y) will also work

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.origin.y);
```

No, this will not give you the size, it will give you the x and y position of your button, the button size is:

```
NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"%f",button.frame.size.height);
```

and you can get the center of your button like:

```
CGPoint center = [button center];
```